# Hibernate Create Criteria to join the same table twice - tried 2 approach with 2 difference error

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, criteria

I would like to create create criteria for the following native sql.

Unfortunately, I hit error of duplicate associate path when use createCriteria twice.
When I try to use Restrictions.sqlRestriction. It unable provide the SQL that I want.

**Try 1: Create Criteria - duplicate associate path**

```
 Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria( Company.class );
                 criteria.createAlias( "customerCategories", "c1" );
                 criteria.add( Restrictions.in( "c1.customerCategory.customerCategoryId",
                         company.getBaseCustomerCategoryId() ) );
                 criteria.createAlias( "customerCategories", "c2" );
                 criteria.add( Restrictions.in( "c2.customerCategory.customerCategoryId",
                         company.getPromoCustomerCategoryId() ) );
```

**Try 2: Create SQL Restriction - ORA-00920: invalid relational operator because of "where"**

```
  Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria( Company.class );
                 criteria.add( Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
                         "INNER JOIN Company_Customercategory a on {alias}.companyId = a.companyId and a.CUSTOMERCATEGORYID = ?",
                         company.getBaseCustomerCategoryId(), LongType.INSTANCE ) );
                 criteria.add( Restrictions.sqlRestriction( 
                         "1=1 INNER JOIN Company_Customercategory b on {alias}.companyId = b.companyId
 and b.CUSTOMERCATEGORYID = ?", 
                         company.getPromoCustomerCategoryId(), LongType.INSTANCE) );
```

*Wrong Result*

```
select this_.* from Companies this_ where 
  INNER JOIN Company_Customercategory a 
  on this_.companyId = a.companyId 
  and a.CUSTOMERCATEGORYID = 1
  and 1=1 INNER JOIN Company_Customercategory b 
  on this_.companyId = b.companyId 
  and b.CUSTOMERCATEGORYID = 6
```

**Expected SQL**

```
select * from companies c
  inner join Company_Customercategory a
  on c.companyId = a.companyId
  and a.CUSTOMERCATEGORYID = 1
  inner JOIN Company_Customercategory b
  on a.companyId = b.companyId
  and b.CUSTOMERCATEGORYID = 6
```

Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: How to convert from native sql to use **criteria**?

Comment: Post Entity source codes. Read how to post questions correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an old Hibernate bug [HHH-879](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-879) on the problem of `org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path` opened 2005 and still open...

Other issue is closed without solution [HHH-7882](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7882)

So the option 1) is rather not suitable.

But in the comments of the above bug an usefull *workaround* is mentioned using `exists`

So use twice `sqlRestriction` with `exists` and a correlated subquery filtering the propper category. You will get only *companies* connected to both categories.

```
crit.add( Restrictions.sqlRestriction( 
  "exists (select null from Company_Customercategory a where {alias}.company_Id = a.company_Id and a.CUSTOMERCATEGORYID = ?)",
  1, IntegerType.INSTANCE ) );
crit.add( Restrictions.sqlRestriction( 
  "exists (select null from Company_Customercategory a where {alias}.company_Id = a.company_Id and a.CUSTOMERCATEGORYID = ?)",
  6, IntegerType.INSTANCE ) );
```

This leads to the following query which provides the correct result

```
select this_.COMPANY_ID as COMPANY_ID1_2_0_, this_.COMPANY_NAME as COMPANY_NAME2_2_0_ 
from COMPANIES this_ 
where exists (select null from Company_Customercategory a 
              where this_.company_Id = a.company_Id and a.CUSTOMERCATEGORYID =  ?) and 
      exists (select null from Company_Customercategory a 
              where this_.company_Id = a.company_Id and a.CUSTOMERCATEGORYID = ?)
```