# Create same join multiple times hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to create a query that uses the same join multiple times. An example would look as follows:

```
select * from a 
join b b1 on b1.id=a.id
join c c1 on c1.id=b1.id

join b b2 on b2.id=a.id
join c c2 on c2.id=b2.id

where b1.attribute = "a" and c1.attribute = "b"
where b2.attribute = "c" and c2.attribute = "d"
```

I need to do this utilizing Hibernate Criteria. I was thinking that something like this should work:

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria(a.class, "a"); //a would be the class representing table "a"
Criteria criteria1 = criteria.createAlias(b.class, "b1").createAlias(c.class, "c1");
Criteria criteria2 = criteria.createAlias(b.class, "b2").createAlias(c.class, "c2");
```

However, I am getting a QueryException: duplicate assocation path exception. I have seen this so: [Hibernate Create Criteria to join the same table twice - tried 2 approach with 2 difference error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54918173/hibernate-create-criteria-to-join-the-same-table-twice-tried-2-approach-with-2), but this solution doesn't work for me I think, and it also implies it is not possible. Has anyone else had better luck? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible with the legacy Hibernate Criteria API. You should rather use the JPA Criteria API, especially because the legacy Hibernate Criteria API was deprecated in Hibernate 5 and removed in Hibernate 6.